# Replace Worn Rubber Cover Over Grohe Ladylux Cafe 33 755 Kitchen Sink Spray Head

Tags: repair

My 11-year old Grohe Ladylux Cafe Model 33 755 kitchen sink faucet still works well but the rubber cover over the spray head button is torn and needs to be replaced.  Grohe and other suppliers sell a replacement spray head for $85-$115.  I just want to replace the worn rubber cover.  While I'm at it, I'll soak the entire head in a 50/50 mix of vinegar/water to dislodge any calcium accumulations from our well water.  Can someone provide info on how to get the rubber cover and a diagram showing how to disassemble/assemble the spray head?

Answer (score 1):

Call Grohe customer service and tell them to send you a free replacement part and instructions/diagram: [grohe](http://www.grohe.com/us/5685/services-for-you/warranties/):

Residential Products: We provide the following warranties on all GROHE products to the original purchaser, installed in a residential setting. This warranty is effective for all faucets sold after January 1, 1997.
Mechanical Warranty: A Limited Lifetime Warranty is provided on all mechanical parts to be free from manufacturing defects in materials and workmanship under normal use for as long as the original purchaser owns their home.
Finish Warranty: A Lifetime Warranty is provided on all GROHE product finishes to the original purchaser against manufacturing defects in materials and workmanship

Comment: I called Grohe customer service in reference to the the the spray head button cover and was told that the cover is out of stock and will no longer be carried by Grohe.

Answer (score 0):

The faucet membrane can be replaced separately and not the entire spray piece. Here is the link for the particular model you mentioned: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B006WCIUCU?keywords=grohe%20faucet%20parts&qid=1445040330&ref_=sr_1_9&sr=8-9](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006WCIUCU)